# Error al querer convertir un valor tipo Model a String en Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Si me pueden orientar un poco con este problema, quiero convertir a string un valor que viene de un modelo.

Modelo:

```dart
class UsuarioModel {
  int? id;
  String imei;
  UsuarioModel({this.id, required this.imei});
  factory UsuarioModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UsuarioModel(
        id: json["id"],
        imei: json["imei"],
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"id": id, "imei": imei};
}
```

DbHelper con sqlite:

```dart
Future<UsuarioModel?> getUsuarioByImdei(String imei) async {
  final db = await database;
  final resultado =
      await db!.query(usuarioTable, where: 'imei = ?', whereArgs: [imei]);
  return resultado.isNotEmpty ? UsuarioModel.fromJson(resultado.first) : null;
}
```

Inserto a la db con un future:

```
Future _insert() async {
  final user = UsuarioModel(
    imei: imei
  );
  await db.nuevoUsuario(user);
}
```

El problema es cuando quiero recuperar el dato guardado. En un StatefulWidget uso un Future asi.

```dart
Future getUser() async {
  user = await db.getUsuarioByImdei(itemUser);
}
```

Aqui me sale el error

> 'await' applied to 'String', which is not a 'Future'.dartawait_only_futures
> A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'UsuarioModel'.
> Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'UsuarioModel'.

Alguien me puede orientar por favor.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de dato es `itemUser`? Se supone que debería ser un `string`

Comment: Si es un string (late String? itemUser = userCtrl.text.trim();)

Comment: Me parece entonces que el problema puede ser la variable `user`

Comment: getUser() no tiene un return apropiado por lo que deberias reemplazarlo por Future getUser() async {
  return db.getUsuarioByImdei(itemUser);
}